# Caption in renderTable Shiny

Tags: r, formatting, shiny

I try to output a table with a caption using reactive expression, but it doesn't work. I used the following code:

```
output$table1 <- renderTable({
 table <- makeTable()
 return(table)
     }, caption="TEST")
```

Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the `caption` is being partially matched by other arguments to the `print.xtable`, so by specifying them, we can get the argument through:

```r
library("shiny")
library("xtable")

data(tli)

# use HTML to style the caption
html_caption_str <- as.character(shiny::tags$b(style = "color: red", "A styled caption"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text_caption <- renderTable({
    head(tli, 5L)
  }, caption = "Sample Data",
  caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "bottom"), 
  caption.width = getOption("xtable.caption.width", NULL))

  output$html_caption <- renderTable({
    head(tli, 5L)
  }, caption = html_caption_str, caption.placement = "top")
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("text_caption"),
    tableOutput("html_caption")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was more interested how to do it within xprint options for renderTable(), any suggestions ?

Comment: @brumberg please review the above answer to see if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: ... and, with the above answer, you can use caption = "<b> Sample Data </b>" if you want to print it bold, and, if you want black text color: caption = "<b> <span style='color:#000000'> Sample Data: </b>"

Comment: @mlegge would you also know how to edit the font of the caption (color and size)? Thanks for your answer, very useful still today!

Comment: @Angelo I've added an example of how to use the HTML tags and style attribute to change the caption

Comment: @mlegge wow! thank you! if you don't mind, there are a couple of small tiny errors in your solution: 1) you need a second closing parenthesis at the end of the html_caption_str row. 2) the parenthesis after "caption = html_caption_str" should be deleted. Anyway, you have been incredibly helpful, thank you

Comment: @Angelo fixed. You might check out the `DT` package if you're working with tables in Shiny, it offers much more customization in my experience: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/

Comment: @mlegge thank you for the suggestion. I tried that package but there I face bigger layout issues that I don't know how to face, so I thought to start with tableOutput that seems a little bit more simple.